# PHP form: Call to undefined function: str_ireplace()

Tags: php, forms, undefined, fatal-error

I have a problem with my php form, after you fill out the form and click on the submit button you recieve an error

---> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: str_ireplace()

I dont know what is going on with it :( Help would be much much appreciated

This is a part of the code:

```
<?php

    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .

    // Set email variables
    $email_to = 'office@victum.sk';
    $email_subject = 'Form submission';

    // Set required fields
    $required_fields = array('fullname','firma','telefon','email','comment');

    // set error messages
    $error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Prosím zadajte krstné meno.',
    'firma' => 'Prosím zadajte názov firmy.',
    'telefon' => 'Prosím zadajte kontakt.',
    'email' => 'Prosím zadajte správnu formu email adresy.',
    'comment' => 'Prosím zadajte poznámku pre pokračovanie.'
    );

    // Set form status
    $form_complete = FALSE;

    // configure validation array
    $validation = array();

     // check form submittal
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] =                                                   remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field]))      array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= htmlspecialchars($key) . ': ' . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br>\n";
}

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content, $headers);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

      function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

      function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
       return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:",      "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
   }

     ?>
```

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: I forgot - - - > this is the form - - - > please try it out and see for yourselves
http://oila.sk/kontakt.php

Comment: Check the manual on [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/str_ireplace) from which PHP version it was supported. Then switch providers.

Comment: Regarding your email validation regex: https://emailtester.pieterhordijk.com/test-pattern/Nzg

Comment: this is the version of PHP Im using

Comment: here is all the info http://oila.sk/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_ireplace` was implemented in PHP 5. If you're using a version older than 5, this would explain why the function you're attempting to call doesn't exist. There really is not any other explainable reason why you'd be encountering such an error.

If you're stuck on PHP 3.x or 4.x, you can use `preg_replace` instead of `str_ireplace`, with slightly modified definitions:

```
function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
  return preg_replace(array("/\r/", "/\n/", "/%0a/", "/%0d/", "/Content-Type:/", "/bcc:/","/to:/","/cc:/"), '', $field);
}
```

Really, the only change requires is surrounding each value to be removed with forward-slashes.

Comment: Joshua Burns 
THANK YOU VERY MUCH MAN !